# React js question image stucked on part to emphasie it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Hi guys i am stuck on a task where i had to move an element from one div to another on clicking with a transition delay (animation is second priority).

At bottom of page i have 3 icons, once i click on the leftmost icon an input box appears with autofocus that opens keyboard in mobile devices

So how do i move the  icon from inital div  to the input box div on click?

Note : In desktop computer keyboard wont popup but the basic idea is to send the mic icon inside the input box div with a little animation, so no matter where the input box is placed on screen the mic icon should go over there

Comment: Check out framer motion - https://www.framer.com/motion/

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach:**

You should remove this part of the logic:
`showInput && <Home ...` (or move you navigation bar outside the Home component. It's up to you)
Then you can create a modifier for your CSS class called `.mic`, e.g.: `.mic--active`.
Next you should pass `isActive={showInput}` prop to the Home component. This way you will get information if the button should be active.

And some CSS magic:

```
.mic {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.mic--active {
  right: 0;
}
```

I know it's not perfect ;). You can improve styles later.

**More complex approach:**

You can use the Framer Motion plugin: https://www.framer.com/motion/

I think Shared Layout from this library is perfect for this case:
https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-shared-layout/#animate-between-components